# What common combat actions does the Fascinate status effect block?

Tags: concentration, pathfinder-2e

The Fascinate status effect says that it prevents a creature from using actions with the Concentrate trait. Casting a spell with a verbal component is included here, which seems to be the most common action a creature might use in combat, so at first glance it seems like Fascinate is primarily useful for disabling spellcasters.

I want to know if it has any other common combat uses apart from disabling spellcasters. It's rather difficult to catalogue all the other actions with the Concentrate trait, however. From a cursory glance, the Barbarian's Rage action, as well as the Command an Animal actions both have the concentrate trait.

Are there any other common actions that non-spellcasters might use in combat, which have the Concentrate trait?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, there is a few more

Other than actions related to casting spells and rituals, here are a few more that require the *concentrate* trait:

- Activate a magic item;
- The [badger](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=14) animal companion's rage;
- Barbarian's [Rage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=3), [Shake it Off](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=139), [Moment of Clarity](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=131) and a few more rage-related [Barbarian Feats](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?Traits=18);
- An alchemist identifying alchemical items with a single action ([Alchemical Savant](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=93)), and using a [Revivifying Mutagen](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=97);
- A druid changing their plant form using [Verdant Metamorphosis](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=346);
- A champion's [Mercy](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?Traits=24);
- An orc activating their [Superstition](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=85);
- A couple of [Fighter Feats](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?Traits=71), like [Incredible Aim](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=391) and [Determination](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=415);
- A monk's [Knockback Strike](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=464);
- A ranger's [Hunter's Aim](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=496) and [Targeted Shot](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=533);
- A bunch of *metamagic* feats from [Wizards](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?Traits=166), [Sorcerers](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?Traits=148), [Clerics](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?Traits=26), [Druids](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?Traits=19) and [Bards](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?Traits=19);

On top of that, a few skill uses also have the concentrate trait, but those worth noting here are:

- [Arcana](https://2e.aonprd.com/Skills.aspx?ID=2), [Lore](https://2e.aonprd.com/Skills.aspx?ID=8), [Nature](https://2e.aonprd.com/Skills.aspx?ID=10) and [Occultism](https://2e.aonprd.com/Skills.aspx?ID=11), to identify a spell and *Recall Knowledge*;
- [Deception](https://2e.aonprd.com/Skills.aspx?ID=5) to tell a lie;
- And a few more that may be worth checking out under [Skills](https://2e.aonprd.com/Skills.aspx?General=true);

Comment: More generally, here's a list of everything with the (concentrate) trait: https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=32